# link btn working but looks like normal text

Tags: asp.net, css, asplinkbutton

I have a link btn, which when clicked performs the task it should. However it does not appear as a link btn it just looks like a normal piece of text.

I have narrowed it down to somewhere in my css file the text-decoration for that property is being set to none.

However there are too many references to go through each one to figure out which it is.

Can I just write a new css which will over write the previous one?

my attempt at this is:

```
a.linkBtn {
      text-decoration: underline;
      color: blue
 }

<asp:Repeater id="rptChecklistRecords" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table class="detailstable FadeOutOnEdit">
        <tr>   
          <th style="width:200px;">Title</th> 
          <th style="width:200px;">Timestamp</th>    
        </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
         <tr>                  
           <th style="width:200px;">
                 <asp:LinkButton id="linkBtn" CssClass="linkBtn" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' OnCommand="LoadCheckListRecordEntry"/>
           </th>  
           <th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Timestamp") %></th>  
         </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </table>
</FooterTemplate>
```

my code being:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="linkBtn" CssClass="linkBtn" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' OnCommand="LoadCheckListRecordEntry"/>
```

Comment: Hi, any rendered html so i can inspect your situation ? Like, what DOCTYPE is used ?

Comment: To help find what css is tied to the link, you can use inspect element in chrome. That should narrow it down if you want to find the original css.

Comment: know you have to put the css selector after previous `a` selectors... like making the last in your css file. The newer definition overrides the previous ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the !Important tag.  Look at this article http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm.

This tag allows you to override other settings.